# how to debug Rule in crawlspider?

Tags: python, scrapy

scrapy shell is a great tool to debug xpath expression,but is any tool or method to debug the  Rule in crawlspider ?
which means how could I know the Rule works as I desire.

my rules is :

```
rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'/search*',restrict_xpaths="//a[@id='pager_page_next']"), follow=False),
        #Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'/chart/[\d]+s$'), callback='parse_toplist_page', follow=True),
    )
```

and it don't follow the links I desired,so how to debug?any example?

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried the Scrapy `parse` command?

```
scrapy parse <URL>
```

Where `<URL>` is the URL you want to test.

It will return all links extracted (which will be followed) from that url.

You can use the `--noitems` argument to only show links, and the `--spider` argument to specify the spider explicitly.

```
scrapy parse <URL> --noitems --spider <MYSPIDER>
```

For more information on debugging spiders see:
http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/debug.html

> *This answer provided by Pablo hoffman on the users group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/scrapy-users/tOdk4Xw2Z4Y*

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so, I usually have to let the spider loose and review what sites it's hitting in the command prompt.  Sometimes I can't kill the program with a control C and have to pull up my task manager and kill the entire command prompt.   It's a pain.

Comment: if we only can see it in the command prompt,it's really a pain,maybe you are right,no way to debug rule.